# How to resolve snakeyaml NoSuchMethodError: getStyle()

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

In my spring boot application, I am using snakeyaml to parse a YAML file. I get the following error though when using the library:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.ScalarNode.getStyle()Ljava/lang/Character;
```

I am using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
  <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  <version>1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have a hint for resolving this error?

**Edit:**

The error seems to occur when parsing spring's application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8084
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is due to [this change](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/commits/22d5128240f5115c15f7995e2c0543ba1e784332):

> Refactor ScalarNode - use enum ScalarStyle instead of Character

You can either roll back to SnakeYaml 1.19, which is the last release before this change, or wait for [Spring Boot to support SnakeYaml 1.20+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13191).

Comment: version 1.19 causes "illegal reflective access" on jdk 9

Comment: @cybersoft See [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/issues/393/warning-an-illegal-reflective-access). Fixed in 1.20, bummer.

Comment: yes, I know, but I use Spring Boot 2 and [it does not work yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13191) with snakeyaml 1.20+

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. I just wanted to add context for other people having this problem. I don't know of any solution, apart from using an older jdk.

Comment: Thanks @flyx. I changed  mine to the latest version of snakeyml, it  solved the issue.

Answer (score 17):

You need to update to SnakeYml 1.23, they fixed the incompatible API change introduced in 1.20.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
  <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  <version>1.23</version>
</dependency>
```